# Make Samba report 0 bytes free to Windows

Tags: windows, samba

I have a Debian server running my samba share and use Win11 clients to mount it.

Everything is working, I just had to change the dfree command to

```
#!/bin/sh
df $1 | tail -1 | awk '{print $2" "$4}'
```

per https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/network_administration_guides/using_samba_book/ch08_06_02.html because of different mounting points etc.

For a particular share I intentionally want to report it as "0 bytes free" always. I tried setting the second parameter $4 to "0" - Windows now shows "1 MB free of ...".
Setting it to 1 yields "1 KB free of". The latter I actually understand, since sizes are given in KB. But why does "0" default to 1MB? Setting it to any other size also yields this value in KB. But I want it to be 0!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a work-around:

Setting

```
block size = 2048
```

or any value higher than 1024 tricks Windows into turning the "1 KB free" into "0 bytes free".

I have not noticed any side effects with regards to transfer speeds and changed block-size.

As long as no proper solutions is known, I'll mark this one as answered.